# Migration tips for ray.rllib.models: DeprecationWarning: `Model` has been deprecated. Use `ModelV2` instead

Tags: migration, reinforcement-learning, ray, rllib

For migration from ray 0.x to ray 1.x, `ray.rllib.models.Model` must be replaced with `ray.rllib.models.ModelV2`.

Are there any migration guidelines describing how to do this properly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are none.

https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/29724#issuecomment-1292777342

However, specific questions can be asked [on the forum](https://discuss.ray.io/c/rllib/7).